# Stored procedure performance issue when grabbing data from many secondary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me explain the scenario of my stored procedure: I have to populate a table for which columns are coming from several tables. Below is one example table out of the several tables that I am using in my query

Data

```
PrimaryID1              PrimaryID2         KeyID       Data
--------------------------------------------------------------     
001                       0011              1           abc1
001                       0011              2           abc2 
002                       0021              1           xyz1
```

Since the granualar data is in 'PrimaryID1' and 'PrimaryID2' I am using correlated query based on the 'KeyID' to differentiate different fields in my destination table that I am populating. I am also dealing with huge amount of data in each of the 7 to 8 tables of data. Initially I had all the correlated queries in one single SQL statement, but that didn't work out (obviously!!). Then I separated each set of table into separate CTE part and then tried to insert into the final query, later I came to know CTEs absolutely do nothing about query performance, so I jumped to temp tables, populated each set of data into separate temp tables created non-clustered indexes in each of the fields that I am using in the table and finally tried to join it in the final query, but still this too didn't work out.

Let me explain the query that I have written here. I am taking data from two tables one happens to be `PrimaryTable` and another happens to be `Secondary` table. The granular data for `PrimaryTable` is in `PrimaryID1` and `PrimaryID2` but in `SecondaryTable` the granularity further goes down to `KeyID` and its respective data column `Data`. So there are 8 secondary tables that I am dealing with each different to one another, hence I end with queries for each secondary tables with a host of columns for it. This is how the query that I have developed looks like. In total I have around 280 odd columns in my query coming from 8 different secondary tables.

Query:

```
SELECT
  PP.PrimaryID1,
  PP.PrimaryID2,
  (SELECT PPA.Data1
   FROM SecondaryTable1 PPA
   WHERE PPA.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND
         PPA.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 AND PPA.KeyID = 1) AS DataField1,
  (SELECT PPA.Data2
   FROM SecondaryTable1 PPA
   WHERE PPA.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND
         PPA.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 AND PPA.KeyID = 2) AS DataField2,
  (SELECT PPA.Data3
   FROM SecondaryTable1 PPA
   WHERE PPA.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND
         PPA.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 AND PPA.KeyID = 3) AS DataField3
FROM  
   PrimaryTable PP
```

I am dealing with 8 such secondary tables with the count of records ranging from 28 million to 100 thousand. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Have you got indexes covering all the fields of your join conditions?

Comment: Yup !! I have indexes covering all the KeyID fields in each of the tables including the PrimaryID1 and PrimaryID2 fields in all the tables.

Comment: And moreover should I be having these each set of query from the secondary tables as a CTE or into a temporary table, which is the best option for me !! As temp tables have an option of indexing (again!!)

Answer (score 0):

For your sample, you should be able to use a simple JOIN. Joins are generally more efficient than nested subqueries (although, knowing nothing about your indexing, it's hard to tell for *sure* if it solves your performance problem)

```
SELECT
  PP.PrimaryID1,
  PP.PrimaryID2,
  PPA1.Data1 AS DataField1,
  PPA2.Data2 AS DataField2,
  PPA3.Data3 AS DataField3
FROM  PrimaryTable PP
JOIN SecondaryTable1 PPA1
  ON PPA1.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND PPA1.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 
 AND PPA1.KeyID = 1
JOIN SecondaryTable1 PPA2
  ON PPA2.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND PPA2.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 
 AND PPA2.KeyID = 2
JOIN SecondaryTable1 PPA3
  ON PPA3.PrimaryID1 = PP.PrimaryID1 AND PPA3.PrimaryID2 = PP.PrimaryID2 
 AND PPA3.KeyID = 3
```

Comment: But unforunately there are many such KeyIDs in each of the eight secondary tables like I had mentioned earlier, and would this perform better than a correlated query if I create that many inner joins ??(please explain)

Comment: @PadmaPrakash Yes, a join, even if big, should perform much better than many correlated queries since databases are well optimized for joins. Of course the only way to know for _sure_ is to test it with your actual data.

Comment: Yes, I am changing the code with your suggestion, so far performance is better. Hoping for the best.